# Trouble getting value from Checkbox in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I have the following checkbox

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<p class="hint grey"><asp:checkbox runat="server" ID="chkBox"/><asp:literal runat="server" ID="warningTxt"></asp:literal></p>

<div class="clear"></div>

<br/>
<table>
<tr><td>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSubmit" 
                    runat="server" 
                    Text="Agree" 
                    ToolTip="Agree"  
                    UseSubmitBehavior="true"
                    OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" 
                    CausesValidation="true"
                    ImageUrl="~/img/buttons/agree-button.gif" />
                    </td><td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;"><img src="img/buttons/print-button.gif"/></a>
                    </td></tr></table>
                </form>
```

And in code behind

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ErrorMessage.Text = String.Empty;
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        if (chkBox.Checked)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", false);
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = "Tick the alert statement";
            ErrorMessage.CssClass = "error";
            //errorTable.Visible = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Now for some reason in Firefox, when I tick the box and click on submit I get the error message "Tick the alert statement", but its fine in Chrome. So just why firefox isnt picking up the value in checkbox correct ?

Comment: Can you check your code? Your XAML dosent have a checkbox

Comment: @Tom - what XAML? This is webforms?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language

Comment: @Tom - This is _not_ WPF _or_ Silverlight, so not XAML involved. It is a webforms application.

Comment: sorry it has the checkbox now

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you. Yeh ok xml not xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the  `CausesValidation="true"` attribute. Its the only thing I can see that could be causing problems.

Comment: Hey tom, tried in but still happens. Works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE the checkbox doesnt seem to be checked in code behind even if it is when clicking on button

Comment: Have you checked javascript is enabled in FF/IE ?

Comment: Yup javascript is enabled, but does that even matter for this ?

Comment: Yes, .net uses javascript to trigger things like postbacks. You error has to be client side (thus javascript) if it works on some browsers but not others. If you change the imagebutton a a standard button does it work?

Comment: Hey Tom, yup that was it. I had several JS files in my master page and played around with moving them 1 by 1 seeing which one was causing the issues and found it eventually. Was just called general.js, im not sure what piece of code in this file was causing it but I didnt need it included so removed it and worked fine again.